# How to use Post Custom Metadata in Post Titles and Post Permalinks

Tags: url-rewriting, post-meta, rewrite-rules

I am very new to WordPress. How can I use post custom metadata in place of Post Titles, and as the Post Permalink? For example, instead of `domain.com/the-post-title`, the permalink would be `domain.com/$postcustommetadata`.

I [posted my idea in the WPORG support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/want-to-customize-parmalink-or-slug-how?replies=1#post-2379306). I have a general idea, but don't know how to implement it, because I don't yet fully understand WordPress conventions, classes, etc.

Thanks

Plzz HeLp

Comment: Please go back and rewrite your post in a way where you don't need to use uppercase (shouting) characters. This is for later readers too. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes for the question? This sounds like a valid question. Perhaps the downvotes are due to the way the question is written? If so: consider that English may not be the OP's first language. :)

Comment: Please Someone help i found here very big wordpress coder and i think I can Get help from your side if you don't understand my idea i can explain it again more clearly please help out

Comment: What you're asking for is a **fairly advanced** WordPress topic, and likely involves familiarity with [the WordPress Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).

Comment: @ChipBennet removed downvote after edit.

Answer (score 2):

This will do.

The slug is saved on the wp_posts while custom fields are on the wp_posts_meta. If you want to make it like that you can use an action hook on save_post that will get the value of the custom fields and saves it as the post slug.

Here is the code

```
add_action('save_post', 'set_slug');

function set_slug($post_id){
    $new_slug = get_post_meta($post_id,'custom-slug', true);    
    $post_args = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => $new_slug,
    );

    wp_update_post($post_args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for customizing the permalink for specific posts, pages or categories, try the [Custom Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/) plugin. I've had much success with it before.