# How to Use metada Value in Url and is it possible?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, post-meta, rewrite-rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Post Custom Metadata in Post Titles and Post Permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30502/how-to-use-post-custom-metadata-in-post-titles-and-post-permalinks)

hii i want to know that how can i use my metadata value for post url which i add with my every post in custom field
First of all is this possible to make url with that and fetch post data with value.
Like domain.com/metadata_value

And if it is possible where become the Wordpress POST PERMALINK Function? that i can edit that manually And How ?

And is thiS safe and Faster Method or it can crate troubles or can damage my word press Speed ?and how much effect on speed and SEO

Thanks

Comment: Do you need exactly this format `domain.com/metadata_value`? Why don't use `domain.com/?meta_key=meta_value`?

Comment: because using this one domain.com/metadata_value my seo will remain good, and this domain.com/?meta_key=meta_value URl possible then we can convert in in this too domain.com/?meta_value using .htaccess but know problem is how to replace url with my custom field value

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Comment: Thanks for Answer but i am looking for more clear answer if any example or code you can put relating to my idea that will be more easy for me to understand :)

Comment: Just go to the above url, there is excellent example.